# Asterisk dialplan: execute context

Tags: asterisk

This is my dialplan:

```
[default]
exten => 100,1,Background(beep)
exten => 100,n,Goto(test,1,1)
exten => 100,n,Background(beep)
exten => 100,n,Hunup()


[test]
exten => 1,1,Dial(SIP/0622423078@provider)
```

I want that the context `default` execute the context test. I gues that Goto is not the right function. So what I want is: you hear two times a beep and in the meantime it dials a phonenumber.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the auto dial out.

```
    exten => 100,n,System(sh /root/test.sh 0622423078)
```

And this is the test.sh

```
    echo "Channel: SIP/provider/$1
    Context: fop
    Extension: 1
    " > /var/spool/asterisk/outgoing/test.call
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need on extension 1 go as described in context test you have do

```
[default]
exten => 100,1,Background(beep)
exten => 100,n,Goto(test,1,1)
exten => 100,n,Background(beep)
exten => 100,n,Hunup()

include =>test
[test]
exten => 1,1,Dial(SIP/0622423078@provider)
```

if you need on some other extension do extension 1 in context test, you can do something like this

```
[default]
exten => 100,1,Background(beep)
exten => 100,n,Goto(test,1,1)
exten => 100,n,Background(beep)
exten => 100,n,Hunup()

exten => 101,1,goto(test,1,1)

[test]
exten => 1,1,Dial(SIP/0622423078@provider)
```

Both will not realize task you described. That task is not doable this way.
You can play sound OR dial. You can't dial&play sound, except variant with Musiconhold

For musiconhold you can set music which have 2 beeps and ringing, and set that in dial command parameter.

Comment: My goal is to dial a phonenumber and the dialed phonenumber will hear a automatic message. But the user (who dialed extension 100) needs to go to the next priority. So I will hear 2 beeps and in the meantime another call will be made (independent)

Comment: You have inspect vicidial.org project. It is unlikly you do something like that yourself, you are using wrong words and concepts.